# What does the crown on this icon mean?

Tags: diablo-iii

I noticed a small, yellow crown on my character icon while in a co-operative game today. I was the party leader. Is that what this crown indicates?

[image: Diablo 3 Portrait Crown]

**Updates:**

- For the record, I found [this](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/6893700671) after further searching, but it
  does not add much.
- I've posted the question [here](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?848138-What-does-the-crown-on-this-icon-mean), too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the crown indicates that you are party leader.

Comment: Incidentally, I tried for about half an hour to find an official page to support this so I could provide a link as supporting evidence, but it just doesn't appear to be mentioned out there. You'll just have to take my word for it ;)

Comment: I was in a game this evening. Player 1 (P1) created the game and I saw he had the crown. I was P2. Later, P3 joined, and later HE had the crown. But he said that he saw the crown on P1, at the same time that I only saw it on P3.

Comment: @SabreWolfy I have no idea what was happening in that case.